# Wagtail blog post table of contents

Tags: django, wagtail

Is there a way to create a table of contents for a [wagtail](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.6.2/) site which is being used as a blog. More specifically I want to create a table of contents for each blog post.

For example I have created a `BlogPost` page model containing a `StreamField` for sections within a blog post. The stream field contains a heading and a rich text field. This allows me to create blog posts with multiple headings / sections.

Blog post model:

```py
content = StreamField(
    [("article_section", ArticleSectionBlock())],
    null=False,
    blank=False,
)
content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
    StreamFieldPanel("content"),
]
```

Article Section Block:

```py
class ArticleSectionBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
    sections = blocks.ListBlock(
        blocks.StructBlock(
            [
                ("header", blocks.CharBlock(required=False)),
                ("content", blocks.RichTextBlock(required=False)),
            ]
        )
    )
```

What I would like to do is be able to create a table of contents at the top of each blog post with links to each section within the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, I think your `ArticleSectionBlock` can be simplified to:

```
class ArticleSectionBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
    header = blocks.CharBlock(required=False))
    content = blocks.RichTextBlock(required=False))
```

Your `content` StreamField is already defined to be a list of `ArticleSectionBlock`s, so there's no need for `ArticleSectionBlock` to be a list itself. (If you do intend the StreamField to be a list of lists, the answer here still applies, but you'll need to adjust the template to use nested `{% for %}` loops, and keep in mind that children of a `ListBlock` don't have unique `id` properties.)

On your template, you can loop over `page.content` to get a list of block objects with `value`, `block_type` and `id` properties, each corresponding to one `ArticleSectionBlock`. By looping over it twice, you can output a table of contents followed by the content itself:

```
<ul>
    {% for block in page.content %}
        <li><a href="#{{ block.id }}">{{ block.value.header }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

{% for block in page.content %}
    <h1><a id="{{ block.id }}">{{ block.value.header }}</a></h1>
    {{ block.value.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

As alternative to using `block.id` as the anchor ID, you can use `{{ forloop.counter }}`.